# How to set background to transparent in Google timeline chart?

Tags: css, google-visualization

I am trying to set the background of Google timeline chart to transparent.[Timeline Chart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline)

Tried using

```
backgroundColor: 'none'
backgroundColor: 'transparent'
```

nothing seems to work.

Also I tried using

```
alternatingRowStyle: false
```

to remove the alternating colors in the rows. It does not work either. Any other ideas?

Comment: `backgroundColor: 'transparent'` should work in modern browsers (that is, everything after IE 8), but it doesn't appear to be working, so I'd call it a bug.  Filed a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1526) on it; you can "star" the issue to receive updates on a fix.

Answer (score 10):

Use this to **style the alternating rows like the non-alternating ones** (works now, until Google implements this option):

```
svg g:first-of-type path {
    stroke: #e6e6e6;
}
svg g:first-of-type rect:not(:last-child) {
    fill: #ffffff;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Related but different: Do you know how I can change opacity of the bars on the timeline to 20%?

Comment: @AndrewKoper I no longer have this code handy, but if you inspect the other elements in using the inspector in the browser you should be able to find the lines. Then try adding `fill-opacity: 0.2` to them.

Comment: Thanks! Worked: svg rect { fill-opacity: 0.2; }

Comment: I know this is a bit late but I'm trying to do a similar thing that is I want to change the background color to white completely instead of the default alternating colors. The only difference is that I'm using a React Chart component to do the same thing. Please can you tell me how to do that inside of the React Chart component that they provide? Here is the link to the documentation that they provided but they didn't tell how to keep a color uniform and remove the alternating color for every row. https://react-google-charts.com/timeline-chart . I have also asked a similar question today.

Answer (score 6):

This is terribly hacky, but does get the job done provided Google's SVG markup doesn't change.  The container of the timeline is specified by the first "g" element.  All "rect" therein can be made transparent using the **fill-opacity** style.

```
svg g:first-of-type rect {
  fill-opacity: 0;
}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/kgto8oqw/1/

Obviously this needs more work to accommodate styling of gridlines etc. but you get the idea.

Comment: I know this is a bit late but I'm trying to do a similar thing that is I want to change the background color to white completely instead of the default alternating colors. The only difference is that I'm using a React Chart component to do the same thing. Please can you tell me how to do that inside of the React Chart component that they provide? Here is the link to the documentation that they provided but they didn't tell how to keep a color uniform and remove the alternating color for every row. https://react-google-charts.com/timeline-chart . I have also asked a similar question today.

Comment: Just add this to the options 

`alternatingRowStyle: false`